# FadeIn / FadeOut Slider not fading out (JQuery / Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm working on a slider to fade in and out. It fades in correctly but the slide instantly disappears instead of fading out. Do you have any idea of why is this happening and any changes that you would do in the code?

I appreciate your help and suggestions :)

```js
$(".slider > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() {
    $('.slider > div:first')
        .fadeOut(2400)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(2400)
        .end()
        .appendTo('.slider');
}, 5000);
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 3rem; 
}


.slider {
  background-color: #fff; 
}

.slider__slide img {
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
  <body>
  <div class="slider">  
    <div class="slider__slide"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/6464/desk-technology-music-white.jpg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="Image 1"></div>
    <div class="slider__slide"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/712321/pexels-photo-712321.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="Image 2"></div>
    <div class="slider__slide"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/715546/pexels-photo-715546.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="Image 3"></div>
</div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set `position: absolute` on `.slider__slide`. you need to use `absolute` position because you trying to put the images on each other, well an element with absolute position can do this, but by default an element have `static` position, `static` or `relative` can't overlay on each other.

```js
$(".slider > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() {
    $('.slider > div:first')
        .fadeOut(2400)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(2400)
        .end()
        .appendTo('.slider');
}, 5000);
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 3rem; 
}


.slider {
  background-color: #fff; 
}

.slider__slide {
position: absolute;
}

.slider__slide img {
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
  <body>
  <div class="slider">  
    <div class="slider__slide"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/6464/desk-technology-music-white.jpg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="Image 1"></div>
    <div class="slider__slide"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/712321/pexels-photo-712321.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="Image 2"></div>
    <div class="slider__slide"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/715546/pexels-photo-715546.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="Image 3"></div>
</div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Pedram! That solved the issue :) 
Could you please give me an explanation of why was that happening and why position absolute solved the problem? Cheers!

Comment: @Rafa Don't forget to give the `.slider` relative position.

Comment: @VXp Cheers!! :)